# How to make them all the sam speed (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, tween

I currently have an animation that rotate infinitely but it's just too fast to begin with... I tried lowering the fps to 12 but it would just be skip.... Is there a possibility to make the animation slower by this code:

```
//Import TweenMax
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

//Save the horizontal center
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;

//Save the width of the whole gallery
var galleryWidth:Number = infiniteGallery.width;

//Speed of the movement (calculated by the mouse position in the moveGallery() function)
var speed:Number = 0.02;

//Add an ENTER_FRAME listener for the animation
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveGallery);

function moveGallery(e:Event):void {

    //Calculate the new speed
    speed = -(0.02 * (mouseX - centerX));

    //Update the x coordinate
    infiniteGallery.x+=speed;

    //Check if we are too far on the right (no more stuff on the left edge)
    if (infiniteGallery.x>0) {

        //Update the gallery's coordinates
        infiniteGallery.x= (-galleryWidth/2);
    }

    //Check if we are too far on the left (no more stuff on the right edge)
    if (infiniteGallery.x<(-galleryWidth/2)) {

        //Update the gallery's coordinates
        infiniteGallery.x=0;
    }
}
```

here is the [demo »](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/perfect-optical/)

Comment: adjust the speed?
var speed:Number = 0.01;
speed = -(speed * (mouseX - centerX));

Comment: yes but if I do that it moves the stops the animation right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a smaller number than 0.02 in `speed = -(0.02 * (mouseX - centerX));`